# XML to formatted text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML in the following format:

```
<Order>
  <Customer>
     <Name>kapil</name>
     <AddressLine1>ABC</AddressLine1>
     <PostCode>12345</postCode>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
     <Name>Soniya</name>
     <AddressLine1>XYZPER</AddressLine1>
     <PostCode>54321</postCode>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
     <Name>kapil</name>
     <AddressLine1>ABC</AddressLine1>
     <PostCode>12345</postCode>
  </Customer>
</Order>
```

And I want the text file in a particular format as

```
Soniya    XYZPER   54321
Kapil     ABC      12345
```

I want to do it via XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pad a string with spaces in XSLT 1.0 you can use a named template like this:

```
<xsl:template name="ppad">
    <xsl:param name="str" />
    <xsl:param name="chr" select="' '" />
    <xsl:param name="len" select="0" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($str) &lt; $len">
            <xsl:call-template name="ppad">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="concat($str, $chr)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="len" select="$len" />
                <xsl:with-param name="chr" select="$chr" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$str" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And then call it with the string and length as parameters:

```
<xsl:call-template name="rpad">
    <xsl:with-param name="str" select="Name" />
    <xsl:with-param name="len" select="16" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: thanks a ton Jorn...but can u please implement it on my example above and post..i will be highly appreciated....Actually i am new to XSLT  :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use XSL-FO and a XSL-FO processor, which could help you format your output (a table disposition for your results in your case) and output it to various formats (plain text, PDF ...)
For starters, you should check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/default.asp), and use Apache FOP - an open source solution - to process your XML documents.
As far as I am concerned, I've used XSL-FO to generate PDF from XML files.

Comment: I can't use XSL-FO ,because my requirement says i only have to use XSLT

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
>

<xsl:template match='/Order'>
  <xsl:for-each select='Customer'>
    <xsl:value-of select='Name' />
    <xsl:value-of select='AddressLine1' />
    <xsl:value-of select='PostCode' />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This doesn't address the ordering (which you haven't specified), and getting everything to line up in columns, which might be tricky...

Comment: Thank's for your help Ned but...
That's exactly i want to do...all columns should be properly lined up....i.e. the text must be formatted...every new address and postcode should get start from the other one

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced Jorn Horstmann's answer to include lpad and rpad

```
<xsl:template name="rpad">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:param name="len" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="chr" select="' '" />
    <xsl:call-template name="pad">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$str" />
        <xsl:with-param name="len" select="$len" />
        <xsl:with-param name="chr" select="$chr" />
        </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="lpad">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:param name="len" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="chr" select="' '" />
    <xsl:call-template name="pad">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$str" />
        <xsl:with-param name="len" select="$len" />
        <xsl:with-param name="chr" select="$chr" />
        <xsl:with-param name="justify" select="'right'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="pad">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:param name="len" select="0" />     
    <xsl:param name="chr" select="' '" />
    <xsl:param name="justify" select="'left'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($str) &lt; $len">
            <xsl:variable name="newStr">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$justify = 'left'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($str,' ')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',$str)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:call-template name="pad">
                <xsl:with-param name="len" select="$len"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="justify" select="$justify" />
                <xsl:with-param name="chr" select="$chr" />
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$newStr" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>            
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

To right pad the string 'myvalue' with blanks to 20 chars use:

```
<xsl:call-template name="rpad">
    <xsl:with-param name="str" select="'myvalue'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="len" select="20" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

To left pad the string 'myvalue' with blanks to 36 chars use:

```
<xsl:call-template name="lpad">
    <xsl:with-param name="str" select="'myvalue'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="len" select="36" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

or call pad directly specifying the text justification desired (ie. left or right)

```
<xsl:call-template name="pad">
    <xsl:with-param name="str" select="'myvalue'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="len" select="36" />
    <xsl:with-param name="justify" select="'right'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```