# Xml to text with formatting

Tags: xml, text, formatting, xslt

I am having a xml file as:

```
<Order>
  <EP>
  <Name>Generation Date</Name>
  <Value>2009-08-04+05:30</Value>
  </EP>
  <EP>
  <Name>NoOfRecords</Name>
  <Value>100</Value>
  </EP>
 <OrderLineItems>
   <OrderLineItem OrderDateTime="2007-01-01T17:09:04.593+05:30>
   <Customer>
      <FullName>Mrs S </FulName>
   <Address>
     <AddressLine1>ABC</AddressLine1>
     <AddressLine2>XYZ</AddressLine2>
   </Address>
   </Customer>
   <EP>
      <Name>DealerAccount</Name>
      <Value>00000000000</Value>
   </EP>
 </OrderLineItem>
 </OrderLineItems>
</Order>
```

Where the OrderLineItem tag is repeating. Now I want to convert this xml to a text file using xslt. The format of flat file is fixed and it's as follows:

```
00000000000010107     Mrs S       ABC  XYZ 
00000000000150709     Mr x        PQR  TWR
```

where the first column contains the Dealeraccount and orderDate(time removed) second field is name and third and fourth field are addressline 1 and addressline2 respectively.
Please note that the formatting of text file is must and I am also having the length of each field such as length of name is varchar2(50) and so on.

Comment: Please include details of what you've tried so far, all your questions so far look like you're asking us to do your work for you.  You'll get a much better response from StackOverflow if you show that you've made an effort.

Comment: Also, this looks very similar to your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240712/xml-to-text-with-formatting

Comment: Well i am sorry if u felt that but  i had really worked hard on that and i am able to convert it to text but i am not able to preserve the formatting.
Ya earlier i asked the question and then i tried to implement the solution from stackoverflow but even after trying those i was unable to get my solution.As i am new to stack overflow i did not knew that we also have to post our own tried method..well i can tell u that for the next line i was using variable as <xsl:param name="line-seperator value="'&#13;&#10;'">
but stil the formatting is lost.
So now can u help me in that

Comment: What formatting? All I see is plain text.

Comment: Whoops, correct link to earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238268/xml-to-formatted-text-using-xslt

Comment: That's fine Vivek, but like I say, if you post the xlst code that you have so far then people will be able to help you better, and it show's you're putting in the effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally i got it..here is the solution

```
<xsl:template name="ColumnSeparator">
        <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="' '"/>
        <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="ColumnSeparator">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

And then simply call this template using:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ColumnSeparator">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="50-string-length(Customer/FullName)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work - for the exact formatting, you'll need to tweak the `<xsl:text>` portions - add more spaces or other delimiters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="Order">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OrderLineItems/OrderLineItem" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="OrderLineItem">
    <xsl:value-of select="EP/Value"/>
    <xsl:text>              </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Customer/FullName"/>
    <xsl:text>     </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Customer/Address/AddressLine1"/>
    <xsl:text>     </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Customer/Address/AddressLine2"/>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can't do much more in terms of formatting raw text output in XSLT - it's really quite limited that way, unfortunately.

Marc

Comment: To solve the OP's problem, the values should be padded to a fixed length (different but constant for each column). Example function: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_pad-string-to-length.html

Comment: Good tip, thanks - but again - it's an XSLT add-on, it's not available in straight-up XSLT itself.

Comment: Oops, I hadn't looked to closely at that link. But googling "xslt pad string" seems to yield many examples in standard XSLT.